# How to run test method by the testfixture parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

I have a test class and a class like below.

```
public class Foo
{
    private IDbOjbect _db;

    public Foo(string conn)
    {
        _db = new DbOjbect(conn);
    }

    internal Foo(IDbObject db)
    {
        _db= db;
    }

    internal bool TestOne()
    {
        if (_db.CurrentDbType == DBType.Oracle)
        {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    internal bool TestTwo()
    {
        if (_db.CurrentDbType == DBType.SqlServer || 
            _db.CurrentDbType == DBType.SqlServerCE)
        {
            //do something
            return true
        }
        return false;
    }

    internal bool TestThree()
    {
        if (_db.CurrentDbType == DBType.MySql || 
            _db.CurrentDbType == DBType.PostgreSQL || 
            _db.CurrentDbType == DBType.SQLite)
        {
            //do something
            return true
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void RunProcesses()
    {
         TestOne();
         TestTwo();
         TestThree();
    }
}

[TestFixture("sqlserver")]
[TestFixture("sqlserverce")]
[TestFixture("oracle")]
[TestFixture("mysql")]
[TestFixture("sqlite")]
[TestFixture("postgre")]
public class Tests
{
   private string _conn;
   private Foo f;

   public Tests(string conn)
   {
       _conn = conn;
   }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        db = new Mock<IDbObject>();
        switch (_conn)
        {
            case "sqlserver":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.SqlServer);
                break;
            case "sqlserverce":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.SqlServerCE);
                break;
            case "mysql":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.MySql);
                break;
            case "postgre":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.PostgreSQL);
                break;
            case "sqlite":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.SQLite);
                break;
            case "oracle":
                db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(DBType.Oracle);
                break;
        }

        f = new Foo(db.Object);
    }

   [Test]
   public void TestOne()
   {
       Assert.IsTrue(f.TestOne());
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestTwo()
   {
       Assert.IsTrue(f.TestTwo());
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestThree()
   {
       Assert.IsTrue(f.TestThree());
   }
}
```

When the _conn is oracle, I want to be run the TestOne method.
When the _conn is sqlserver or sqlserverce, I want to be run the TestThree method.
When the _conn is mysql,sqlite or postgre, I want to be run the TestTwo method.
How can I do this ? Is there an attribute of nunit for this ?

Comment: How about using an `if`?

Comment: I don't want to do using if. I want more professional thing, like attribute.

Comment: You should indeed look into either combining the `Test` or making two different `TestFixture`'s. The reason is that `TestFixture` is intended to run all tests for every set of arguments. If only one `Test` should apply, it means that either two tests are essentially the same test, or the entire `TestFixture`'s are different. BTW, this may help re-considering your object model; maybe it's wrong?

Comment: @Jared No. If I decide to using an if, I will have to use a lot of if. I think, use a lot of if is not professional.

Comment: @sinanakyazici I would greatly disagree about `if`'s being professional.  The case of a big ugly list of `if` and or `if`/`else` can be something else, but to say that one of the fundamental decision making constructs of a language is unprofessional is simply incorrect and in the case of this or that decisions I'd be hard pressed to see an issue with it.  At the end of the day though it will boil down to using the correct tool in the correct way.  One of your recent code examples on your blog uses and `if` and that's out there for the world to see....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That really isn't the intended use of `TestFixture`...  If you don't want to use an `if`, why not just be explicit in your tests?  You can use a `TestCase` for values you expect to pass a certain test.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests {

    [TestCase("test1")]
    public void FooTest_One(String value) {
        Foo f = new Foo(value);
        Assert.IsTrue(f.TestOne());
        Assert.IsFalse(f.TestTwo());
    }

    [TestCase("test2")]
    public void FooTest_Two(String value) {
        Foo f = new Foo(value);
        Assert.IsTrue(f.TestTwo());
        Assert.IsFalse(f.TestOne());
    }
}
```

Assuming you want to test more than two values, you can also add additional `TestCase`'s for values that correspond to the expected behavior:

```
[TestCase("test1")]
[TestCase("test1.1")]
public void FooTest_One(String value) ...

[TestCase("test2")]
[TestCase("test2.1")]
public void FooTest_Two(String value) ...
```

This gives you the added benefit of testing for the cases that are supposed to fail.  I'm not sure if it matches your real situation, but it is always important to test for failure in addition to expected passing values.

---

**EDIT**  If you truly need dynamic behavior for the `Foo` class based on the DB type, your best bet would be to create an abstract class to represent the intended behavior.  Using that, your DB-specific implementation would be called at runtime.  Here's an abbreviated example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    protected IDbOjbect _db;

    private DBType _type;
    public DBType Type {
        get { return _type; }
    }

    public Foo(DBType type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    internal abstract bool RunTest();

    public void Connect(IDbObject db) {
        _db = db;
    }

    public static Foo Create(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case "oracle": return new FooImpl_Oracle();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public sealed class FooImpl_Oracle : Foo {
    internal FooImpl_Oracle() : base(DBType.Oracle) {
    }

    internal bool RunTest() {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
}

[TestFixture("oracle")]
public class Tests {
    private Foo f;

    public Tests(string conn) {
        f = Foo.Create(conn);
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp() {
        Mock<IDbObject> db = new Mock<IDbObject>();
        db.Setup(x => x.CurrentDbType).Returns(f.Type);
        f.Connect(db);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestOne() {
        Assert.IsTrue(f.RunTest());
    }
}
```

This will preserve the meaning of `TestFixture`, which is to run all tests in the fixture using a specific configuration option.  It may not be an exact fit for your real situation, but hopefully these two ideas give you some direction.

Comment: I am sorry, my question was incomplete to I wrote the question simply. The using testcase is logical. I used it, but there was be a problem. I use the Mock in the SetUp Method. So I have to create the foo object before the test method is run.  How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you add your setup and mocks usage to your question with this example?  It sounds like you really need two separate test fixtures if the behavior is so different based on how the object is constructed.

Comment: Added another option based on your edits...  Bottom line is, you can't do precisely what you are looking for with `TextFixture` unless you place the conditionals throughout your test.  If it is truly annoying to do so, you might think about refactoring your classes to support testability a bit better.

Comment: Thank you @jheddings. I can't use the last way that you said. I need to solve this with one class. Must not be multiple class. But the first way that you said helped me. I achieved this by using TestCase with some changes.